# How to identify right tail cutoff of a distribution?

Tags: r, distribution

I have a distribution of gene lengths like this:

```
Gene  Length
Gene1  5
Gene2  6
Gene3  400000
Gene4  1000
Gene5  25000
Gene6  10
Gene7  50
Gene8  4
Gene9  100
Gene10 2000
```

Is there a way for me to identify the right/upper tail of these samples in a distribution in R? Would it need to be log transformed/normalized to get tails (can tails only be identified in a normal distribution?) or can I identify a tail from a skewed plot?

Currently I am working with just identifying the upper quantile:

```
top75 <- filter(df, Length > quantile(df$Length, 0.75))
```

But I am trying to find out if there is a more specific way in R to calculate the cut-off for the right tail of a distribution in particular? Sorry if maybe this is a simple question, I don't have a statistical/computational background so I suspect I'm not searching using the right terms to find my answer, any help/guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Example input data:

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5", 
"Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10"), Length = c(5L, 
6L, 400000L, 1000L, 25000L, 10L, 50L, 4L, 100L, 2000L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Maybe relate it to the spread of data, as is done with probabilities. So something like > mean + 2SD. Think this might be more of a best practices issue and not coding issue though.

Comment: How do you define "tail"?

Comment: Unless you can translate your goal into statistical term you won't find a (good) solution. When you talk about a "cut-off" what exactly does that mean to you? Also, is this count data?

Comment: There's absolutely no way your data come from a normal distribution, they are extremely skewed.  That means solutions premised on standard deviation are not appropriate.  You could estimate some percentile to use as a threshold, say the 75th.  Another approach would be to look for outliers, commonly defined as values outside the range `[Q1 - 1.5*IQR, Q3 + 1.5*IQR]`, where `Q1` is the 25th percentile (first quartile), `Q3` is the 75th percentile (third quartile), and `IQR` is the inter-quartile range `Q3 - Q1`.  For your data these yield the same result, but with more data that could change.